# Can men wear platinum, diamonds, etc.?

Tags: sharia, men, adornments

I know it is Haram for men to wear gold, how about platinum, or say diamond. Is that Haram too?

Answer (score 3):

The platinum is not a gold. It just another metal. So wearing this is not Haram, even it contains some diamonds.

Here is the Link for your Ref.:
http://www.sistani.org/english/qa/search/59376/

Comment: Gold is also a metal. What makes it different from platinum?

Comment: Platinum and Gold are two different types of metal. Due to Ahkam men can not put on gold and do prayer. Gold has two types of color which one of them is in gold color and the other is in silver color. Some people think that they can put on a gold with silver color. But Gold is gold even in silver color. I don't know why it is Haram, but some years ago I read in a scientific article that gold metal prevents the body to build white globule.